# cssmerr_tp_not_trusted command usr bin codesign failed with exit code 1

Tags: iphone, ipad

I am getting error in xcode when i m trying to archive the application file.I have created provision profile to submit to apple.I want to make archive of app file.Please help me to find the problem.

Comment: I tried this and it is exactly what happen. Please refer here http://stackoverflow.com/a/5751079/1323131

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the provisioning profile, you also need to download and install your developer certificate and the Apple WWDR intermediate certificate from the Provisioning Portal. Follow the instructions in the 'Certificates' section of the provisioning portal. You need to download your developer and intermediate certificates and drag them into the Keychain application.

The certificates authorize you to use the provisioning profile.

Comment: Thanks Robin but i have downloaded and installed developer and the Apple WWDR certificate from Provisioning Cretificate.

Answer (score 0):

Install "Apple WWDR" cirtificate http://developer.apple.com/certificationauthority/AppleWWDRCA.cer and make sure that all the certificates Trust parameter is set to "Use System Defaults" in Keychain Access